# Filtering repeated values from another layer?

Tags: qgis

I'm a complete noob when it comes to programing, and a not so experienced user of QGIS, at least not in depth.

Here's my problem: 
I have two layers, lets say A and B.
When I create a new feature in layer B, the attributes window shows up to fill with information. One of this fields is meant to have values exclusively from a specific attribute from layer A. Lets say "Code".

I've managed to configure that field in layer B as a drop list that shows only that attribute from layer A.

The problem is it shows ALL attributes from that column, even if they are repeated.
For example, if layer A has 100 features with code "1", the drop list in the attributes of layer B will shows the code "1" 100 times.

So, how can I limit the drop list in B so it shows only exclusive values, instead of all existing values, even if repeated?

Comment: maybe create an intermediary query handling these duplicates ?

Comment: I could create another layer with only the single values from A, but then... it's another "useless" layer...
Is there a way to filter it via script or something?

Comment: With a query you can decide to filter your initial data (using operator like **select distinct** ...) then you can build your form and make it depend on this filtering query. it would be dynamic